# How do I convert a NSString into TIS-620 encoded string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

In the apple document, I can see that there's a way to convert from UTF8 string to ASCII string like this

```
NSData *asciiData = [theString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *asciiString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:asciiData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

But my app requires a TIS-620 string to post to a site so I try to do the same thing

```
NSData *asciiData = [newPost.header dataUsingEncoding:kCFStringEncodingMacThai allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *asciiString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:asciiData encoding:kCFStringEncodingMacThai];
NSLog(@"%@", asciiString);
```

The output I got is like this ???????????.

Does anyone know how to convert the NSString to TIS-620 properly? 
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, TIS-620 is a subset of ISO-8859-11, so you should use the string encoding kCFStringEncodingISOLatinThai instead of kCFStringEncodingMacThai.

Also, a CF encoding cannot be directly used to decode an NSString. You need to convert the CF encoding into NS encoding first.

```
NSStringEncoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingISOLatinThai);
NSData *asciiData = [newPost.header dataUsingEncoding:enc allowLossyConversion:YES];
```